# i want to buy learning ros for robotic programming book, will it work for ros indigo also?

Tags: 3d-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it is written that it is for ros hydro, im using ros indigo, so little confused although i think it will work for indigo also cas both are latest version, but dont know exactly that it will work for ros indigo also.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234433/i-want-to-buy-learning-ros-for-robotic-programming-book,-will-it-work-for-ros-indigo-also?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [publisher's website](https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/learning-ros-robotics-programming) (I'm guessing that's the book since no link was provided in the question), that book is for Hydro. Now, you *can* use it for Indigo, but I suspect that you may run into trouble trying to use Hydro code with Indigo.

I highly recommend the comprehensive ROS by Example (Indigo) series. They are comprehensive, cover many different aspects of ROS, and includes two Github repos that you can use as inspiration for your own work. Plus, there is a Google Group for the books and the author, @Pi Robot, frequents this site as well. [Volume 1](http://www.lulu.com/shop/r-patrick-goebel/ros-by-example-indigo-volume-1/ebook/product-23032353.html) covers:

- Real and Simulated Robots
- Operating Systems and ROS Versions
- Reviewing the ROS Basics
- Installing the ros-by-example Code
- Installing the Arbotix Simulator
- Controlling a Mobile Base
- Navigation, Path Planning and SLAM
- Speech Recognition and Synthesis
- Robot Vision
- Combining Vision and Base Control
- Dynamixel Servos and ROS

and [Volume 2](http://www.lulu.com/us/en/shop/r-patrick-goebel/ros-by-example-volume-2-indigo/ebook/product-22251662.html) covers:

- Task Execution using ROS
- Creating a URDF Model for your Robot
- Controlling Dynamixel Servos: Take 2
- Robot Diagnostics
- Dynamic Reconfigure
- Multiplexing Topics with mux & yocs
- Head Tracking in 3D
- Detecting and Tracking AR Tags
- Arm Navigation using MoveIt!
- Gazebo: Simulating Worlds and Robots
- Rosbridge: Building a Web GUI for your Robot

I've used these at work and they have helped me considerably. Please note that I am in no way attached to these books financially, I just think that they are excellent.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0